# Erasing db entries on Wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I used Wamp when building a sign-in at for my company.  In the table the first 40 entries are test entries.  My boss asked if I could erase these entries.  My concern is if I erase those will it have an effect on the other entries (customers singing in) that have been made.  I only took one db class in undergrad and the professor told us that you don't change entries unless you have too.  It is easy to screw up a db and can be hard to fix it.  I am wondering if anyone has any advice about if it is worth erasing the first 40 entries, or could it mess up the other entries.   Basically if its not broke is is worth fixing?

The front end of the app is android written in Java and XML.  The back end in PHP that talks to the db.

Comment: Well, we could preach here about having a dev and live server, but I guess you already know that. Assuming your DB was set up correctly there should be no problem with removing the test cases. It's hard to say for certain though, as you're a little vague in the description of the specific system.

Comment: one advise: do a mysqldump + backup before you start. if things are messed up, after deleting, you can switch back to the old db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting generally entries is fine, just understand the DB structure. Do the ID's for those users get referenced elsewhere, how does the DB connect data? Basic principle is as follows. On your development environment migrate the database downstream (from production to development). On dev (and dev only!) delete the 40 entries. Test. I assume you don't have unit testing in place (write unit tests!) but you can still test all the functionality manually. Honestly this should not hurt anything.

If you have to do this on production then make a backup of the DB and test out deleting the entries. If it doesn't work then drop the DB and re-import the backup. This is not advised because if you fail to import in a decent amount of time people are going to take notice. If this is your first database dump and re-import then test it on a useless database or duplicate the production database and name it something different.

Also you should look up frameworks for your PHP if they don't currently have one. Laravel has 'Migrations' which allow you to run code to update your database. This ensures that you can write code on dev, test it, deploy to production and just run the migration (all automatable). Here is some info on it: http://laravelbook.com/laravel-migrations-managing-databases/

Good luck and remember, ALWAYS TEST ON DEV FIRST.